# Some explanation for this lambda function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, lambda, expression

Trying to get my head around how the expression below is evaluated, looking at the returned list:

```
sorted([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], key=lambda x: abs(2-x))
```

which gives:

```
[2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I'm not sure what value `x` in `abs(2-x)` takes. Is it the list elements' position `[0,1,2,..,8]` or the actual elements' values `[1,2,3,.,9]`

Can someone explain?

Comment: x is the actual value. 2 is the closest to 2 so it is sorted to the first place

Comment: Ah I see. so the list is evaluated using `abs(2-x)` and then the result is sorted?

Comment: That is correct @super_ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x` is the actual element.

when writing:

```
key=lambda x: abs(2-x)
```

its exactly such as:

```
def sort_key(x):
  return abs(2 - x)
```

but only the body of the function is passed to `key` when writing `key=lambda x: abs(2-x)`.

list:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

its sorted positions are influenced by the result of `key` when calling that `lambda`.

the actual sort:

```
1 -> abs(2 - 1) = (1) [position]
2 -> abs(2 - 2) = (0) [position]
3 -> abs(2 - 3) = (1) [position]
4 -> abs(2 - 4) = (2) [position]
5 -> abs(2 - 5) = (3) [position]
6 -> abs(2 - 6) = (4) [position]
7 -> abs(2 - 7) = (5) [position]
8 -> abs(2 - 8) = (6) [position]
9 -> abs(2 - 9) = (7) [position]
```

explanation:

- element `1` is giving `1` so its positioned on index `1`
- element `2` is giving `0` so its positioned on index `0`
- element `3` is giving `1` so its positioned on index `1`, but `1` is already occupied, so its positioned next to element on pos `1`
- element `4` is giving `2` so its positioned on index `2`

....

and so on.

Comment: And `abs()` is used to ignore the sign.

Comment: my pleasure to help.

Answer (score 1):

It's the values that are passed to the lambda and it returns the new 'keys' to be used for sorting.

In this case the lambda will return [1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] so the value 2 with the key 0 will move to the front, followed by 1 and 3, which both have index 1, and then the rest of the values.

Comment: Good, gentlemen explanation, I understand.